# Javascript works in Adobe Reader but not in Nitropdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have setup an interactive PDF form with a Javascript button to submit the form by email, extracting data input by the user. The button works fine in Adobe Reader but does nothing in NitroPDF. Is there a problem with the code (see below)?

```js
var cToAddr = this.getField("ComboBox1").value
var cSubLine = "Property Transaction Form " + this.getField("Text1").value
var cBody = "The attached file is the filled-out form. Please open it to review the data."
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody})
```

Comment: have you read: http://support.nitropdf.com/entries/23748707-Javascript ? do you get errors? does anything happen?

Comment: I have contacted Nitro and their only suggestion is that there is a problem with the Javascript. I'm not sure this can be the case as the code works fine when run in Adobe Reader.

There are no error messages. Nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: Hi, is mailDoc a custom function, because I could not find in niro doc? You should also check JS console for errors.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the console and get the following error `GeneralError: Unspecified error cause: => document.mailDoc() => AppSendMail`

Comment: Reference for mailDoc is [here](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/dynamically-setting-submit-e-mail-address)

Comment: It is very likely that Nitro does not know the mailDoc() method (confirmed with http://support.nitropdf.com/entries/24201296-Javascript-Objects ; they do not support the doc object (which makes me wonder about the completeness of that page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the plethora of PDF viewers out there that implement only some of the Acrobat JavaScript API - some more, some less - I recommend testing for the existence of any functions that your document requires before trying to use them. Wrap your code in the snippet below to let the user know that they are using a less capable viewer than what you've programmed the document for.

```
if (typeof this.mailDoc == 'function') { 
  // The viewer can mail documents 
}
else {
  // Warn the user somehow
}
```